# Ícono en el Systray de odoo 16 con badge y click a función

Tags: odoo16

Holaa todos, estoy haciendo un proyecto de curso en Odoo 16 y necesito mostrar un ícono en el systray con un badge que muestre el número de notificaciones existentes y al darle click estas se muestre. He seguido el tutorial "How to Add an Icon in Systray in Odoo 16" de [cybrosys](https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-add-an-icon-in-systray-in-odoo-16) pero no se cómo mostrar un badge con un valor obtenido de una función ni tampoco cómo vincular el click del ícono a una función específica de un modelo que muestra las notificaciones.
Este es el código que tengo hecho a partir del tutorial de cybrosys en el cual quiero llamar a la función "_len_notifications" del modelo notificaciones y mostrar su resultado en un badge y que al dar click en el ícono se ejecute la función "_show_notifications" del mismo modelo, el problema es que no me está funcionando, el ícono se muestra pero no hace nada de las dos cosas, por favor ayuda:

view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<templates xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-name="systray_icon" owl="1">
        <div class="">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" title="Notifications" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="o_MessagingMenu_icon fa fa-bell" role="img" aria-label="Notifications"></i>
                    <span class="badge" id="notification_badge"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </t>
</templates>
```

JS

```
import { registry } from "@web/core/registry";
import { useService } from "@web/core/utils/hooks";
import { Component } from "@odoo/owl";

class SystrayIcon extends Component { 
    setup() {
        super.setup(...arguments);
        this.action = useService("action"); 
        this.rpc = require('web.rpc');
    }
    _onClick() {
        
        // this.action.doAction({
        //     type: "ir.actions.act_window",
        //     name: Notifications",
        //     res_model: "notification.notification",
        //     view_mode: "form",
        //     views: [[false, "form"]],
        //     target: "new",
        // });

        this.rpc.query({
            model: "notification.notification",
            method: "_show_notifications",
        }).then(function () {});
        
        this.rpc.query({
            model: "notification.notification",
            method: "_len_notifications",
        }).then(function (result) {
            document.getElementById("notification_badge").innerHTML = result;
        });
    }
}
SystrayIcon.template = "systray_icon";
export const systrayItem = { Component: SystrayIcon,};
registry.category("systray").add("SystrayIcon", systrayItem, { sequence: 1 });
```

**manifest**.py

```
'assets': {
    'web.assets_backend': [
        'project_course/static/src/js/systray_icon.js',
        'project_course/static/src/xml/systray_icon.xml',],
    },
```

modelo notificaciones

```
from odoo import api, fields, models

class Notification(models.Model):
    _name = 'notification.notification'
    _description = 'Notification Model'
    
    user_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.users', string='User', required=True)
    message = fields.Char(string='Message', required=True)
    status = fields.Selection(string="Status", default="send" selection=[('send', 'send'), ('read', 'read')],)
    
    @api.model
    def _show_notifications(self):
        notifications = self.env[self._name].search([('user_id', '=', self.env.uid), ('status', '=', 'send')])
        if len(notifications) != 0:
            for n in notifications:
                self.env.user.notify_info(message = n.message)
            notifications.write({'status': 'read'})
        else:
            self.env.user.notify_warning(message="There are no notifications")

    @api.model
    def _len_notifications(self):
        notifications = self.env[self._name].search([('user_id', '=', self.env.uid), ('status', '=', 'send')])
        return len(notifications)
```

Ayúdenme alguien por favor, le estaría muy agradecido, gracias

Answer (score 0):

logré resolver el problema usando un código que encontré en [Cybrosys forum](https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-add-an-icon-in-systray-in-odoo-16), lo adapté a un módulo y aquí [bell_systray_notification](https://github.com/cramirezmartin/bell_systray_notification) lo pongo por si alguien más lo necesita. El mismo coloca un ícono en el systray y muestra el número de notificaciones, cada 60s se actualiza este.